# Adding a data in the table dynamically LinqToSQL C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I am beginner in LinqToSQL. I am trying to create a database and add values to my table dynamically.
I create a database in my program as below.

```
public class MyDVDs : DataContext
{
    public Table<DVD> DVDs;
    public MyDVDs(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}

[Table(Name = "DVDTable")]
public class DVD
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Title;
    [Column]
    public string Rating;
}
```

I initialized my database as below. If the database doesn't exists then create one. If the database already exist then add the values in the table. I am not sure how would I add the values in my table.

```
public void CreateDatabase2()
{
    MyDVDs db = new MyDVDs(@"c:\mydvds.mdf");
    if (db.DatabaseExists())
    {
            DataContext database = new DataContext("c:\mydvds.mdf");
            Table<DVDTable> myTable = database.GetTable<DVDTable>();

            DVDTable dvdTable= new DVDTable
            {
                Title= "The Alchemist",
                Rating = "Good"

            };

            var q = from a in database.GetTable<DVDTable>()
                    select a;

            ???????????????
    }
    else
    {
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

I am stuck at adding values in the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb425822.aspx is that your only code? tried `db.AddToDVDs(dvdTable)`?

Comment: Yeah thats my only code. I dont have the method AddToDVDs for my db object.

Comment: or this? `db.DVDs.Add(dvdTable);`

Comment: Sorry it was my stupid mistake. My class was somehow not declared properly. I changed it to partial and then it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.